# How can i stop and continue an execvp() call?

Tags: c++, signals, fork, exec, kill

I wrote a program which stops the time of a child process calling execvp(). The next task is to occasionally stop the child process for a given time and continue it.

```
pid_t child = fork();
if(child == 0){
    // In child process
    execvp(); // e.g. sleep 10
} else {
    // In parent process
    kill(child, SIGSTOP);
    // Do stuff
    kill(child, SIGCONT);
}
```

What i think is happening here is, that kill(child, SIGSTOP) is pausing the child process but not the execvp() process within it. Is there a way to get the pid of the execvp() process and stop it directly?

Edit example:

```
int main(int argsc, char *argv[]) {

int status;

// Fork for processB
pid_t processB = fork();

if (processB == 0) {
    system("~/loop.sh");     
} else {
    for (;;) {
        sleep(5);
        kill(processB, SIGSTOP);
        std::cout << "Should have stopped counting" << std::endl;
        sleep(3);
        kill(processB, SIGCONT);

        // If loop process ended, exit watchDog
        if (waitpid(processB, &status, WNOHANG) == processB)
            _exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Loop.sh

```
counter=0;
while :;
    counter=$((counter+1));
    do echo $counter;
    sleep 1;
done
return 0;
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the process that calls `exec` is replaced by the called executable. Not an expert though.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the process is not halted?

Comment: If i were to call exec with "sleep 20" and pause the process every 5s for 3s while waiting for the child process to finish with wait(&status), the process would end at 24s which cant happen, right?

When i am using my terminal and just calling "ps", it will open another process called "ps" which has a different pid. Thats what got me thinking that i might stop the wrong process with kill(child, SIGSTOP)

Comment: TBH I don't know how `sleep` behaves, whether it follows wall-time, relative time, cpu-time or whatever. I would write a simple program whose behaviour I was sure of.

Comment: Looking at `man 3 sleep`which I imagine is the underlying function that `sleep` calls, it says it counts real time seconds. So the `sleep` process will wake up as soon as 20 seconds have elapsed whatever. Then, if its calling process is halted, it will wait until the next continue (max 3 seconds) giving 20-23 seconds I think.

Comment: I tried doing that. Writing a for(;;) loop that printed numbers every second. Stopping that process obv worked, because it just stopped the child. Then i put that loop into a loop.sh and called it from c++ with system(loop.sh) and i couldnt stop it anymore.

Comment: Re. `"...pausing the child process but not the execvp() process within it"`: they're the same thing (assuming the `execvp` call succeeded).  Can you clarify the problem?  Right now it feels as if you're describing a few symptoms but *not* the underlying problem.

Comment: Also note that using `sleep` here is probably a bad example.  `sleep` or any other program that has fairly strict timing constraints will probably go to some lengths to ensure those timing constraints are met even in the presence of externally induced delays.

Comment: Assuming the execvp() / system(loop.sh) in my testing case, i was not able to stop the process using kill(child, SIGSTOP). The loop just continued counting and so did the execvp() call. It just waited the 20s and then finished the process, which i caught by waiting for it in the parent

Comment: You state `"Assuming the execvp() / system(loop.sh) in my testing case"`.  What `execvp() / system(loop.sh)`?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I hope that example kind of helps..? If i replace the system() with a for(;;) that just counts every second, it will stop. Dont worry about the wait statement at the end. I "just" need to understand how to stop the system() or exec() for that matter.